# How to pass multiple variables on ajax using JQuery

Tags: jquery

In JQuery if you want to pass a variable into ajax the code can be like this

```
$("#productselection").load("/productform", {product: $("#product").val()});
```

What's the right way to load more than one?

Comment: `...load("/productform", {product: $("#product").val(),otherValue:'abc'});`

Comment: You just use a comma to separate the values, `product: $('#selector').val(), product2: $('#selector2').val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass JSON object like

```
$("#productselection").load("/productform", {
    product: $("#product").val(),
    product2: $("#product2").val(),
    foo: "bar"
});
```

For more info visit [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Well slap my face and call me sally. I was sure I did it this way already. Whatever. Thanks!

Comment: @user2567273, We all do some silly mistakes some time. I thinks its time for a coffee or a beer but definately no a slap

Answer (score 1):

You can pass as many values as you want to that second argument:

```
$("#productselection").load("/productform", {
    product: $("#product").val(),
    another: 1234,
    foo: "something else..."
});
```

Read `.load()` documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The jquery api doesn't specifically give a multiple parameter example. Only a return function, a single array of parameters, and a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new object and then pass it, or pass it straight way.

`var data = {
      'product': 'bar',
      'product2': 'bar',
      'product3': 'bar
   }`

$("#productselection").load("/productform", data);

You can aswell pass arrays of data

`$( "#objectID" ).load( "test.php", { "products[]": [ "bar1", "bar", "bar3"] } );`